# False positive in consumer tests for valid and invalid reques(matching multiple contracts)

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

We have the case where we have two different outcomes on the producer side depending on a request one is for success and on which trows error message.

A simplified sample with two contracts:
1)Contract.make {
    request {

```
    method PUT()
    urlPath("/sample")
    headers {
        contentType('application/json')
    }
    body("{\"acc\": \"1234A\" ,\"case\":\"abc23\",\"re\":2018/12/12}")

}


response {
    status BAD_REQUEST()
       }
```

}
2)
Contract.make {
    request {

```
    method PUT()
    urlPath("/sample")
    headers {
        contentType('application/json')
    }
    body("{\"acc\": \"1234\" ,\"case\":\"abc23\",\"re\":2018/12/12}")

}


response {
    status 200
       }
```

}

On the consumer side it is able to match both request where as , when i run the invalid request test case it is throwing org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request

But the for both scenarios i can able to see request and coresponding response, i can able to see in the logs

Can any body help me in this?

Thanks

These are my consumer test cases

1) its sucess request scenauro its working fine it is getting 200

```
enter code here
     @Test
     public void should_update_case_sucess() throws Exception {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
          "http://localhost:8083//sample",
            HttpMethod.PUT,
            new HttpEntity<>("{\"acc\":\"1234\",\"case\":\"abc23\",\"re\":\"20181212\"}", httpHeaders), String.class);
    BDDAssertions.then(response.getStatusCodeValue()).isEqualTo(200);


}
```

2) 
This is the failure scenario which not getting  400 respose instead it is trowing httpclient error,it is not able to invoke target

```
enter code here
   @Test
   public void should_update_case_error() throws Exception {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            "http://localhost:8083//sample",
            HttpMethod.PUT,
            new HttpEntity<>("{\"acc\":\"1234A\",\"caseNumber\":\"abc23\",\"representmentStartDate\":\"20181212\"}", httpHeaders), String.class);

 BDDAssertions.then(response.getStatusCodeValue()).isEqualTo(400);

}
```

Could you help me in this

Answer (score 0):

This will not work cause wiremock has two same requests and two different responses so the first one wins.

What you have to do is to alert the request a little bit to differentiate between the two and that way you'll find the proper response.

Comment: Thank ypou for Quick Response ,The request are not same the acc  value is different in both the cases one is sucees and one is failure case.

Comment: For this two requests i able see the  both request  and response in the logs from the consumer side , but the valid request is working fine is able to match  ,for the invalid request it throwing that particular exception(org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request)

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: for the invalid request it not getting the response  ,it is just throwing an error

Comment: Your setup on the production code side must be wrong. Wiremock did what it was supposed to do unless the stub is broken

Comment: I am able to get the request and response from stubs ,which i can see in logs, but when write test cases corresponding to that request and response in consumer side(which i mentioned above) , one of the test case is failing.

Comment: could you provide more example or docx online to alert or tweak the request a little bit, & how to let wiremock know that it is a different request, because, already in the error scenario, I changed `acc` value to `1234A` which was an `int` to `string`

Comment: Sorry i have no idea what you're talking about. Wiremock understands that those are two different requests. It will respond with proper response. You just fail to read the body due to invalid setup i guess